# How to use version numbers with CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, attachment

Suppose you want to have an ImageUploader, and when an image is uploaded, it is saved using the filename "/image_1.png". Each time a new image is uploaded, the number is incremented: "/image_2.png".

What is a good way to do this?

Do you add a field in the ImageUploader to store the version_number? Or does this field need to be added to the Image model?

What is a good way to increment when a new file is uploaded?

Comment: I think a column in model would be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i=1:10
  filename=[ 'image_'num2str( i )'.txt' ]
end
```

or add '/' before 'image_'

Comment: Please use code blocks when posting code snippet in your answers. For an even greater answer, please also take some time to explain why the given code reply to the question.